# Mathematical identity related to d'Alembert's Principle

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, differentiation

In [Hand & Finch's book on Analytical Mechanics](https://books.google.sk/books?id=A1UhAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=hand%20finch%20analytical%20mechanics&pg=PT17#v=onepage&q=mathematical%20identity&f=false), I came across this mathematical identity Eq. 1.19 in Chapter 1, page 5, which is related to the description of d'Alembert's principle:

$$\dot{\vec{p}} \cdot \delta \vec{r}=\frac{d(\vec{p} \cdot \delta \vec{r})}{d t}-\vec{p} \cdot \frac{d(\delta \vec{r})}{d t}.\tag{1.19}$$

Does this identity have a name and could someone please explain it to me?

Comment: It sometimes goes by the name of product rule ;) Jokes aside, momentum and position can both be time-dependent. Thus, the time derivative of the product $\vec{p} \cdot \delta \vec{r}$ has got two components. One is just brought to the right-hand side of the equation.

Comment: This is an application of the chain rule in differentiation. Notice that the first term on the RHS is a time derivative of the scalar product of two vectors. Apply chain rule to this term and rearrange to obtain the above result.

Comment: I see it now! Thanks. It is simply a re-arranging of the product rule.

Comment: Oh man, that is written strange.  I didn't notice that the first that the first $p$ was actually dotted.  I'm sure it makes more sense in context, but showing everything else as $\frac {d}{dt}$ except for that $p$ makes it harder to see that this is just chain rule.

Comment: @JMac yeah It really confused me! I wish authors would describe what they are doing in precise detail instead of saying "here is a mathematical identity". It would save readers (especially dumbasses like me) a lot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bring over the term on the right, and substitute the notation $\dot{x}\equiv \frac{dx}{dt}$ to get

$$\frac{d(\vec{p} \cdot \delta \vec{r})}{d t} = \frac{d\vec{p}}{dt} \cdot \delta \vec{r} + \vec{p} \cdot \frac{d(\delta \vec{r})}{d t},$$

which is an application of the product rule.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Do you know the Leibniz rule $$ (fg)'=f'g + f (g')\,?$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes this identity has a name, it is the variational equivalent of "integration by part". You are probably familiar with the fact from basic calculus that integration by parts is given by $$\int u.dv = (u.v) - \int v\,du$$

In your equation, if you substitute $v=\vec p$ (that is, $dv=d\vec p$), and $u=\delta \vec r$ , you can then follow the integration-by-part rule and write (multiplying up-and-down by $dt$ each term in both members):
$$\int \frac{d\vec p}{dt}. \delta \vec r dt = \int \frac{d(\vec p . \delta \vec r)}{dt}dt- \int\vec p\frac{\delta \vec r}{dt}dt$$ and therefore, by equaling the left and hand side of integration arguments in the equation, you end up with:

$$ \frac{d\vec p}{dt}. \delta \vec r  =  \frac{d(\vec p . \delta \vec r)}{dt}- \vec p\frac{\delta \vec r}{dt} $$ which is exactly uour equation. As others have said in their comments/answer, this is nothing else than a rearrangement of the product rule (that's really what "integration by parts" actually does)